# How to log user out AFTER viewing JSP page?

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, sap-commerce-cloud

I have a scenario whereby I require a user to be logged out after they view a certain page, but not in the same way as a typical logout page.

As far as the user can tell, they should still be logged in until they then view a further page.

I cannot figure out a way to do this within the Spring framework other than firing off an Ajax request on the page via JavaScript to /logout.

Scenario:
User hits controller -> Return view JSP -> Log user out

Wonder if anyone had any ideas, and if I'm missing the obvious?

Thanks

Comment: When you are returning the JSP page in the controller, you know the user is certainly viewing this page. At the same time that particular controller/service method where you return the specific page you just call the session.invalidate(). That should solve this problem.

Comment: But if I call invalidate in there, by the time the user receives this page they will be in a logged out state already.

Comment: So if you want to avoid sending another request, just make a simple `Thread.sleep` in java..

Answer (score 0):

If the action is based on a frontend behaviour, then you have to implement a front end solution.

Your first idea looks good to me. When the frontend event is triggered, send an ajax request to call the logout controller.

If you need to implement a frontend behaviour to show that the user is logout, you can create your own controller call `authenticationService.logout();` and send the data needed in JSON.